# Scrapy returns no data

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I was trying to scrape this page:

http://www.homeimprovementpages.com.au/connect/hypowerelectrical/service/261890

And I used this code:

```
import scrapy


class HipSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "hip"
    allowed_domains = ["homeimprovementpages.com.au"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.homeimprovementpages.com.au/connect/protecelectricalservices/service/163729",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = HomeimprovementItem()
        item['name'] = response.xpath('//h2[@class="media-heading text-strong"]/text()').extract()
        item['contact'] = response.xpath('//div/span[.="Contact Name:"]/following-sibling::div[1]/text()').extract()
        item['phone'] = response.xpath('//div/span[.="Phone:"]/following-sibling::div[1]/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

And the result is:

```
C:\Python27\homeimprovement>scrapy crawl hip -o h.csv
2016-04-08 17:49:33 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.5 started (bot: homeimprovement)
2016-04-08 17:49:33 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2016-04-08 17:49:33 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'ho
meimprovement.spiders', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['homeimprovemen
t.spiders'], 'FEED_URI': 'h.csv', 'BOT_NAME': 'homeimprovement'}
2016-04-08 17:49:34 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, FeedExporter
, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-04-08 17:49:34 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddl
eware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultH
eadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMidd
leware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2016-04-08 17:49:34 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddlewa
re, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2016-04-08 17:49:34 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
2016-04-08 17:49:34 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-04-08 17:49:34 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 i
tems (at 0 items/min)
2016-04-08 17:49:34 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-04-08 17:49:34 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET http://www.homeimprovemen
tpages.com.au/connect/protecelectricalservices/service/163729> (referer: None)
2016-04-08 17:49:34 [scrapy] DEBUG: Ignoring response <403 http://www.homeimprov
ementpages.com.au/connect/protecelectricalservices/service/163729>: HTTP status
code is not handled or not allowed
2016-04-08 17:49:34 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-04-08 17:49:34 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 276,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 2488,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/403': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 8, 12, 19, 34, 946000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 8, 12, 19, 34, 537000)}
2016-04-08 17:49:34 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

And there was a csv created in the spider folder and it was empty. I cant understand what went wrong. I hope someone can guide me.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The page http://www.homeimprovementpages.com.au/connect/hypowerelectrical/service/261890 has a protection.

All your selectors return an empty array.

```
In [1]: response.xpath('//h2[@class="media-heading text-strong"]/text()')
Out[1]: []

In [2]: response.xpath('//h2[@class="media-heading text-strong"]/text()')
Out[2]: []

In [3]: response.xpath('//div/span[.="Contact Name:"]/following-sibling::div[1]/text()')
Out[3]: []

In [4]: response.xpath('//div/span[.="Phone:"]/following-sibling::div[1]/text()')
Out[4]: []
```

Comment: do you have any idea on how can i bypass this protection?

Comment: It requires subscription from deathbycaptcha.com, so, it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs due to forbidden error(403) which can be seen in your log.
You will have to add custom user agent header while you request these pages.

[A library that lets you add fake user agent headers](https://github.com/alecxe/scrapy-fake-useragent)

Comment: Ok, i will try that and let you know whether it worked, thank you.

Comment: I tried it and nothing changed. May be i have done it wrong, I am new to python and scrapy.